# Hibernate error: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc

**When I run my Hibernate application it shows flowing error:**

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:420)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1326)
    at com.jwt.hibernate.SimpleTest.main(SimpleTest.java:23)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javawebtutor
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:417)
    ... 5 more
```

**I would like to mention that mySQL server version is 5.5 and connector: mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar
and this is my hibernate application's config file named: hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
    <!-- language: lang-xml -->

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

        <hibernate-configuration>
            <session-factory>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javawebtutor</property>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
                <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
                <property name="show_sql">true</property>
                <property name="format_sql">true</property>
                <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create </property>
                <mapping resource="com/jwt/hibernate/student.hbm.xml" />
            </session-factory>
        </hibernate-configuration>
```

**Guide me where is the problem. There is issue regarding connector version or MySQL version mismatch??**

Comment: It seems that mysql-connector jar is not on your classpath. If you run it from IDE probably you misconfigured your build path. If you run it on Tomcat make sure that you put jar into your WAR file or Tomcat lib directory

Comment: I have added mysql-connector jar by clicking on to the build path configuration then add jars and add into lib tab.

Comment: Update your question with details such IDE, how do you run your code etc.

Answer (score 0):

What IDE are you using? Try and add it to your classpath there and then deploy. 
If it is a web app try putting to `WEB-INF/lib`
If it is maven app put the snippet inside your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.34</version>
</dependency>
```